# Consider to dec lare/implement a mapping method: "java.lang.String map(java.lang.Object value)" during to use the Framework MapStruct

Tags: spring-boot, mapstruct

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface MapperThings  {

    @MapMapping(keyTargetType = Object.class, valueTargetType = Object.class)
    Map<String, String> toDto(Map<Object, Object> mapEntity);

    List<Map <String, String>> toListDto(Collection<Map<Object, Object>> listEntity);

    @MapMapping(keyTargetType = Object.class, valueTargetType = Object.class)
    Map<Object, Object> toEntity(Map<String, String> mapDto);

    List<Map<Object, Object> > toListEntity(Collection<Map<String, String>> listDto);


}
```

There is to generate without mistakes  only :

```java
    @MapMapping(keyTargetType = Object.class, valueTargetType = Object.class)
    Map<Object, Object> toEntity(Map<String, String> mapDto);

    List<Map<Object, Object> > toListEntity(Collection<Map<String, String>> listDto);
```

I found temporary decision. But I would want to use the annotation @MapMapping.

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class MapperMoviesAbstract {

    public Map<String, String> toDto(Map<Object, Object> mapEntity) {

        if(mapEntity == null) return null;

        Map<String, String> stringMap = new HashMap<>();

        for(Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : mapEntity.entrySet()){

            String key = (String) entry.getKey();

            stringMap.put(key, mapEntity.get(key).toString());
        }

        return stringMap;

    }

    public abstract List< Map<String, String>> toListDto(Collection<Map<Object, Object>> listEntity);

}
```

According to the MapStruct documentation, using the @MapMapping annotation should generate a class that will perform the conversion.

But I get an error:

> Can't map map key "java.lang.Object" to "java.lang.String ". Consider
> to dec lare/implement a mapping method: "java.lang.String
> map(java.lang.Object value)".

Do anyone have any ideas to do what?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you what to do. You need to provide a way to map `Object` into a `String`.

So you'll need a custom method like:

```
public String objectToString(Object object) {
    // Your custom implementation
}
```

Comment: Please, to made an example your desicion using my the example. Sorry, I understand you. I above to show my decision. How can it correct?